# Rails Scope, Helper Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have three models. One is an Employee, one is an Item, and one is a Transaction that belongs to both Employee and Items. It's a simple app that allows Employees to check in and check out items - 'Transaction' has a boolean column for checked-in/checked-out.

What I'm trying to do is show within the employee/show view the current list of Items that an Employee has checked out. This is some rough code that I sketched out, but I'm not sure that it's going to work, and I was told not to use a lot of nested conditionals in my views anyway.

```
    <% if @employee.transactions.exists? %>
        <h3>Currently Checked-OUT Items</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Asset Tag</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
            </tr>
        <% @employee.transactions.each do |transaction| %>
            <% if item.transaction.last? && transaction.status == false %>
                <tr>
                    <td><% transaction.assettag %></td>
                    <td><% transaction.description %></td>
                </tr>
            <% else %>
            NO CHECKED OUT ITEMS
            <% end %>
        </table>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Basically, I'm trying to:

- checks all employee transactions
- compares the item involved in the transaction and sees if it's the .last transaction record for item
- if it is, *and if it's false*, then it's a current checkout.

Is this a better job for a scope within the Transaction model, or a helper method? I've never used either, I'm really new at rails.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a couple of things in here.

First - create a scope that will fetch last item transaction for you. There's no point in going through al item transactions if you're interested in the last one only, right?

Second, use partials. In this example it's hard to show how I would refactor code to use them (some things doesn't make sense here, ex. where does item variable come from?)

Scope example (take last transaction)

```
@item.transactions.order('created_at DESC').first
```

You can as well add scopes for checkin / checkout

```
class Transaction
    scope :checkin, -> { where(status: true) }
    scope :checkout, -> { where(status: false) }
end
```

Comment: Pro-tip would be also to avoid vaguely named status column. Either rename it to ex. in_stock or use verb status (checked-in, checked-out), aasm maybe?

Comment: I've never used scopes before - would the scope for this first one be something like:

scope :last_transaction, @item.transaction.order('created_at DESC').first

Comment: I suggest you read this Rails Guides part http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes (and Rails Guides in general, always something to learn!)

Answer (score 0):

First,  you are on the right track.  When views get ugly and hard to read because of extensive embedded ruby conditionals and such,  think about moving the logic into a helper.

If you have a typical rails app,  you'll already have app/helpers/application_helper.rb

So you could just create a helper in that file

```
def make_employee_list(employee)

   if employee.transactions.exists?
     content_tag(:div) do
       content_tag(:h3, "Currently Checked-OUT Items")
       content_tag(:table) do
         employee.transactions.each do |transaction|
           #  you get the idea
         end
       end
     end
   end
end
```

Then in your view you could do this:

```
<%= make_employee_list(@employee) %>
```

Comment: How is that solving a problem of a complicated view? Instead it makes generating a viw a nightmare (and takes a looooot longer than regular erb)

Comment: I was kind of thinking the same thing - and I recognize that you're much more experienced than me - but I was having a hard time implementing your solution. Is there an easier way - maybe just a scope or a helper method that doesn't render html?

Comment: Sorry,  yes, as I state in my answer,  content_tag helpers are the more conventional way to go.  I just copied and pasted a helper of mine and hacked it up.  I'll add a simpler example.